# How to render JSON data in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, render, react-dom

This is my people.js file.It contains data of two people.

```
var Data = [
        {
            "gender": "male",
            "name": {
              "title": "mr",
              "first": "ruben",
              "last": "dean"
            },
            "location": {
              "street": "3070 york road",
              "postcode": "LP0 5PG"
            },
            "email": "ruben.dean@example.com",
            "login": {
              "username": "crazydog764",
              "password": "kane",
              "sha256": "58841f853bffca51507549428aee2a6c14863c8219e5a4b563d58a5b97564c92"
            },
            "picture": {
              "large": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/96.jpg",
              "thumbnail": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/96.jpg"
            },
            "nat": "GB"
        },
        {
            "gender": "male",
            "name": {
              "title": "mr",
              "first": "daniel",
              "last": "king"
            },
            "location": {
              "street": "7618 taylor st",
              "postcode": 35059
            },
            "email": "daniel.king@example.com",
            "login": {
              "username": "silvergorilla983",
              "password": "1a2b3c4d",
              "sha256": "df4eeb09df18d02d7fa49534a2cd6a03587d361f17aa7596d8ed7c025c5cb4d4"
            },
            "picture": {
              "large": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/21.jpg",
              "thumbnail": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/21.jpg"
            },
            "nat": "US"
        }
    ]

    module.exports = Data;
```

This is my PeopleList.jsx. Both files are in the same directory.

```
var React = require('react');
var Data = require('people');

var PeopleList = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
              <ul>

              </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = PeopleList;
```

Can anyone tell me how to render both names (Ruben and Daniel) from the people.js file into the screen (within the unordered list)? Please provide code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<ul>
    {Data.map(x => <li>{x.name.first}</li>)}
</ul>
```

Comment: I had forgotten the curly braces before editing, it should work with the current answer.

Comment: Yahh I know but I added it. Now it is working. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using ES6 like this.

```
import {Data} from './path/to/people.json'
```

Then map over it.

```
Dara.map(person => console.log(person.name))
```